# MVC4 Oauth Server SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth

I have a MVC4 Webapp configured with SimpleMembership. I want to develop a Xamarin App that authenticates against this Webapp.
Is it possible to add OAuth Server functionality to the MVC4 Webapp?